# How to efficiently find a non-unique key value documents in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Having a large collections which contain one key as switch their value could be 'on' or 'off' string type.
How to filter a documents in that large collections using switch key?
I can use *`db['collection-name'].find({'switch':'on'})`* query but its not efficient to fetch.
Is there anyway to use index on this key 'switch' to retrieve the results quickly?

Comment: How to make it more efficient really depends on what you are trying to do.  If you want to know how many there are, use `count` instead of `find`; if you want to retrieve a small bit of information about each one, use a projection.  If you really need to retrieve the full document for each all at once, that's going to take some time.

Comment: Kavithakaran Kanapathippillai - Those results are not meant for display in front-end. Is there anyway to create index to fetch the result so quicky.

Comment: Joe - You are right i need to retrieve full docs from collections, Not to know for how many docs in collections.

Comment: Retrieved results in small numbers like 10/100 but have to scan collection in 1Lakh docs.Is there any way to set index?

Comment: Have you tried using a cursor and setting the batch size?

Comment: Will try with batch size.Thank you very much